# Use Excel VBA to Create Validation List

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying create a custom VBA Code to generate Validation List.

My point is put in the follow code a custom Formula, however this basic formula doesn't works.
Any help is be apreciate.

I'm using the following code and it's returning error 1004, how can I solve this?

```
Sub MyVBAList()

    With Selection.Validation

        .Delete
        .Add _
             Type:=xlValidateList, _
             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:= xlBetween, _
             Formula1:="=DESLOC($A$2,0,0,CONT.SE($A$2:$A$100,""<>""))"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the `DESLOC` and `CONT.SE` functions?  I'm assuming they're non-English versions.  I _think_ VBA needs the English versions.

Comment: Looked it up.... `OFFSET` & `COUNTIF`.

Comment: Try using `"=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,""<>""""""))"` - having just `""<>""` in your code results in `"<>"`.  `""<>""""""` will give `"<>"""`.  If that doesn't work stay with your version of the formula, but change the <> bit in the `CONT.SE`.

Comment: Man! This works like a charme! Perfect! And yes my Excel is non-English version (Portuguese).. Tks!!! Your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: I'll have to write it up as a proper answer.